# 301 redirect for specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a setup where two domains share the same .htaccess by adding VirtualHost configuration to one of the domains. The trouble is that if I write a 301 redirect in the .htaccess it applies to both domains.

Is there a condition I can put around a redirect to ensure it only applies to a matching domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can use a RewriteCond to **target only one domain** like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ http://example.com/bar [L,R=301]
```

Comment: but does this allow multiple RewriteRules for multiple pages?

Comment: @LaurenceCope Please ask a new question as this is very old answer that I am probably going to delete since I never heard back from OP

Comment: I think its relevant no matter how old, it comes up in Google but is not a full answer. It's best have all the answers in one question. its a bit silly to ask a new question, be good to get a full answer on the above.

Comment: My answer here is complete and working for the problem asked in OP. Same condition can be used in many rules